# How to modify the size of the legend oof shapes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a simple plot using ggplot2

```
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(iris) +
geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, size = Sepal.Width, fill = Species), shape = 21)
```

I want to reduce the legend size of the Sepal width only (the circles) and I tried

```
    +
   guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=8)))
```

but this did the opposite and affected the legend spicies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legend that says `Sepal.Width` above it is the *size* guide, not the *fill* guide. You don't need to touch guides if you just want the points to be smaller. For that you need to change the size *scale*

Here is the original plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, size = Sepal.Width, fill = Species), 
             shape = 21)

p
```

[image]

If you want to change the range of sizes of the  points, do:

```r
p + scale_size(range = c(0.2, 3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but the size in the figure does not correspond anymore to the legend

Comment: @Tpellirn I thought that is what you wanted. Do you just want to make the points smaller, and have the legend reflect that? `You can simply add `scale_size` to your plot. See my update.